# How can I get grid submitted jobs to inherit job limits?

Tags: sungridengine

I've eliminated core dumps in my C shell using the command "limit core 0". I've noticed that when I qsub jobs, that setting is not inherited even when "-V" is passed. Is there an option to inherit shell limits?

Answer (score 0):

No.  Generally with batch schedulers like Grid Engine you let the scheduler sort that out.    You could send it to a queue with h_core set to 0 though.